# What effects do Buddhist chants have?

Tags: meditation-insight

Does listening to Buddhist chants such the [Wisdom Sutra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dz59yKyxNuU) bring any benefit when working, meditating or other activities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quote on *Buddhist Chanting*. In here it's told why Buddhists chant and the benefits of it. The quote is from an article named ["*The Practice of Chanting in Buddhism*"](http://www.urbandharma.org/udharma2/chanting.html) by Ven. Bhikkhu Dhammasami:

> "Chanting is very common to any religion. Buddhism is no exception in this regard. However, the aim and purpose of chanting is different from one religion to another. Buddhism is unique in that it does not consider chanting to be prayer.
>
> The Buddha in many ways has shown us to have confidence in our own action and its results, and thereby encouraged us to depend on no one but ourselves. This in fact is the sum and substance of His last message in the Mahaparinibbana Sutta. One of the passages in this discourse reads: "Ananda, be dependent on yourself, take refuge in yourself and not in others, by this mean be dependent on the Dhamma, go for refuge to the Dhamma -- the righteous principles".
>
> When a Buddhist does chanting, he is not asking some one to save him from evil nor is he hoping to be given a place in heaven as a result after he dies. Instead, through chanting he may be learning, teaching, philosophising or re-memorising the discourse.
>
> Actually, in the Anguttara Nikaya there are some discourses dealing with chanting like Dhammavihari Sutta. It mentions five categories of people who make use of the discourses.
>
> The first one studies it just for the sake of study without putting it into practice or explaining it to others. He even does not reflect deeply on what he has studied. He is known as 'Pariyatti-bahulo' who is keen on studying it alone.
>
> The second one preaches or teaches what he has learnt from the discourses but does not follow it himself. He is 'Pannyatti-bahulo' who is keen only on teaching.
>
> The third one does chanting. He philosophises about the discourses, trying all the time to satisfy his philosophical thirst. He forgets to make use of as mode or life. He is called 'Vitakka-bahulo' who is eager only to indulge in philosophical aspects of the Suttas (Discourses).
>
> The fourth one is the one who chants the discourses to make them last for a long time in his memory. He memorises and re-memorises. Nevertheless, he does not go further to follow it in daily life. He is 'Sajjhayaka-bahulo' who is enthusiastic only in memorising or chanting the teachings of the Buddha, He may even expect some magical power from chanting.
>
> The fifth and last one is who studies the discourses, teaches them to others, reflects on their philosophical points, chants them regularly and above all actually practices it in daily life. He is the one the Buddha praises to be 'Dhammavihari' -- a practitioner of the Dhamma, which he has learnt from the discourses.
>
> Having reflected on this Sutta, it is left to us to judge ourselves to which category we belong and why we study or chant the discourses.
>
> I would like to dwell a bit more on chanting in general. This is, after all, an All-night Chanting ceremony. It is nothing but right for us to be fully convinced of what we are doing. Initially I did mention that Buddhism is unique because it does not consider chanting to be a form of prayer.
>
> **Then why do we, Buddhists, chant?**
>
> In the olden days, before there were sufficient support materials for study like books, translations and computers we had to memorise to learn a discourse. After we had learnt it, we still had to chant regularly to protect it and hand it down to future generations. If we did not recite it daily we might forget it and omit some part of it. The Anguttara Nikaya says that if the discourses are poorly maintained this will lead to the disappearance of the Sasana. It was so important those days to memorise and chant it regularly. This must have definitely contributed in developing chanting practice. Chanting meant almost for the survival of the Dhamma itself.
>
> Now we have sufficient support materials, why we should then be still chanting? Is there any more reason to do this?
>
> There are some reasons sufficient to continue chanting practice. Regular chanting gives us confidence, joy and satisfaction, and increases devotion within us. This devotion is really a power. It is called the Power of Devotion (Saddhabala). It energises our life in general. I do not know about the others. For me I often have a joyous feeling when the chanting goes right. I become more confident of myself. I see it as a part of developing devotion.
>
> In Buddhist monastic education tradition, chanting and learning by heart still forms a part of it. We study some of the Theravada Abhidhamma texts -- the highest teachings of the Buddha which deal with the ultimate nature of things -- in that way in Burma. We are explained the meaning and how the logic develops in the Abhidhamma. In the night we try to chant without having learnt it by heart. We could do it because of the technique. It is known as evening-class (nya-war) over there. It means a certain technique of studying the Abhidhamma and some of the Suttas. It is very helpful as it helps you to reflect very quickly".

[Lastly, here is a website where you can listen to different Buddhist chantings e.g. *Chinese Pureland and Pali Devotional Chanting*.](http://www.buddhanet.net/audio-chant.htm)

Answer (score 1):

@Lanka answered from the perspective of the Theravada tradition.

From the Mahayana and Vajrayana perspective, you can find the answer [here](http://fpmt.org/education/teachings/lama-zopa-rinpoche/the-benefits-of-chanting-om-mani-padme-hum/) from Lama Zopa Rinpoche:

> Even if you don’t have much intellectual understanding of Dharma, even
>   if the only thing you know is om mani padme hum, still the happiest
>   life is one lived with an attitude free of the eight worldly concerns.
>   If you live your life with the pure attitude free of attachment
>   clinging to this life and simply spend your life chanting om mani
>   padme hum—this six-syllable mantra that is the essence of all
>   Dharma—that’s the purest Dharma.
>
> It looks very simple, very easy to recite. But if you think of the
>   benefits, it’s not at all simple. Here, I’d to mention just the
>   essence of its infinite benefits.
>
> Reciting the Compassion Buddha mantra just once completely purifies
>   the four defeats of breaking the four root vows of self-liberation and
>   the five uninterrupted negative karmas1.
>
> It is also mentioned in the tantras that by reciting this mantra you
>   achieve the four qualities of being born in the Amitabha Buddha pure
>   land and other pure lands; at the time of death, seeing Buddha and
>   lights appearing in the sky; the devas making you offerings; and never
>   being reborn in the hell, hungry ghost or animals realms. You will be
>   reborn in the pure land of Buddha or as a happy transmigratory being.
>
> When one who recites ten malas a day goes swimming, whether in a
>   river, an ocean or some other body of water, the water that touches
>   that person’s body gets blessed.
>
> It is said that up to seven generations of that person’s descendents
>   won’t get reborn in the lower realms. The reason for this is that due
>   to the power of mantra, the body is blessed by the person reciting the
>   mantra and visualizing their body in form of the holy body of
>   Chenrezig. Therefore, the body becomes so powerful, so blessed that
>   this affects the consciousness up to seven generations and has the
>   effect that if one dies with a non-virtuous thought, one is not reborn
>   in a lower realm.
>
> Thus, when a person who has recited ten malas of om mani padme hum a
>   day goes into a river or an ocean, the water that touches the person’s
>   body gets blessed, and this blessed water then purifies all the
>   billions and billions of sentient beings in the water. So it’s
>   unbelievably beneficial; this person saves the animals in that water
>   from the most unbelievable suffering of the lower realms.